# Why Throw An Exception Rather Than Letting The Code Throw It?

Tags: c#, exception

I want the code calling a function to handle any exception raised in the function. If I write:

```
            try
            {
                // Code than may raise an exception
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
```

The exception will be passed back with the callstack. Could I write the following instead and get the same result? Is there any reason to use the `try catch` in this case?

```
             // Code that may raise an exception
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the scenario you've presented, the only reason to catch, and then rethrow, the exception, is if you're doing something else in the catch block, like logging or cleanup. Otherwise, it's entirely a no-op.

Good on you that you're using `throw`, rather than `throw e`, by the way, if you do need this construct. The former preserves the callstack; the latter does not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `try/catch` in that case.

If you were logging any information or encapsulating the exception in a higher-level one, then the `try/catch` would be indicated.